# Create lead in D365 from PowerApps information

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

[image]

When 'Request Quote' is pressed, I want all the info from the text boxes to be sent to Dynamics 365 and for a lead entity to be created and filled out with all info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other data sources, we usually do `SubmitForm`. But for CDS we have to use `PATCH` function.

[Read more](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Urgent-SubmitForm-function-is-broken-when-submitting-to-CDS/m-p/142542/highlight/true#M48975)

```
Patch(
 "CDSEntityDataSource",
 Defaults(CDSEntityDataSource),
 {
   Column1:DataCardValue1.Text,
   Column2:DataCardValue2.Text,
   ...
 }
)
```

Comment: Patch(Leads, Defaults(Leads), {'First Name':'Text First Name', 'Last Name':'Last Name','ZIP/Postal Code':Postcode,'Address 1':'Building Name or Number','Mobile Phone':'Phone number',Email:Email,Ext:'Phone Extension','Company Name':'Company Name',Description:'Description Box'})

Comment: This is the code I had written in PowerApps yet the app would not run because it says there is a field 'subject' that is required for it to work, yet we have no field called subject on the specific entity!

Comment: @ChrisSolar definitely ‘subject’ field is there. assign some value to it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/lead?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9